# "ТамарИн карандаш" или "ТамарЫн карандаш"?

Tags: орфография

Какое окончание является правильным: "ТамарИн карандаш" или "ТамарЫн карандаш"? После сонорных согласных следует писать букву -и- или -ы- ?

Answer (score 1):

-ИН-, разумеется.
Но очень бы хотелось понять логику спрашивающего. Я не в первый раз сталкиваюсь с подобным вопросом (кажется, даже пример *ТамарЫн* "на слуху"), но объяснить не могу.   Причем ранее слышал подобное от носителя русского, вариант родного языка с несмягчаемыми согласными (грузинский, например, что объясняло бы интерес к Тамаре), я исключаю.

~~~
Вот тут вспомнилось, что произношение непалатализованного "Р" перед суффиксами -ИНСК-, было особенностью московского произношения в XVII-XVIII веках, но не помню точно, в каких случаях это имело место. Да и сколько воды утекло с тех пор...

Comment: спасибо! содержательно) логика проста. маячит давно забытое правило, а может и не было его вовсе... После сонорных согласных пишется -ы- А в реале было имя Эльмира, Эльмирин.

Answer (score 0):

Суффикс -ИН-. Мамин, дядин, Тамарин, Петин. 
Правило, регулирующее выбор суффикса,  не припоминаю. После Ц традиционно - ЫН.